# Check HTML form for number of responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

so I need to verify that the course has a title and there are 3 SLOs checked. I have a snippet in Javascript that ensures I have no more than 3, but how can I make sure I have 3 and the there is information in the course description.

```
here is my code: 
var limit = 3;
$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
       this.checked = false;
   }
});


function submitUser(className, slo){
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        cache:false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: {
            json:'{"Course":className,"SLO":slo}'
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#ajax-json').html(data.Course);
            $('#ajax-html').html(data.SLO);
        },
        error:function(error){
            alert('there was an error');  
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });


    });
}
```

and my HTML looks like this:

```
       <div class="pricing-levels-3">
       Course Title: <input class = "text" name = "course" id = "name" value = " "><br>
          <p><strong> Select 3 SLO Outcomes</strong></p>
          <input class="single-checkbox"type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="SLO1">SLO1
          <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="SLO2">SLO2
          <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="SLO3">SLO3
          <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="SLO4">SLO4
          <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="SLO5">SLO5
          <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="SLO5">SLO6<br><br>
          Upload Artifacts:<br>
          Artifact 1: <input type = "file" name ="ArtifactOne"><br>
          Artifact 2: <input type = "file" name ="ArtifactTwo"><br>
          Artifact 3: <input type = 'file' name ="ArtifactThree"> <br>
          <br>
           <button id="btn" onclick="submitUser(document.getElementById('name').value, document.getElementByName('vehicle').value)">Create Class</button>
          </div></form>

  <div id="ajax-json"></div>
 <div id="ajax-html"></div>
```

whenever I submit I get the following error:

`{"error":"key missing: title"}`

any advice on how to get this to work? It doesn't need to be fancy I essentially just need a "yes you have everything" or "no you do not have everything"

This is my JSFiddle page:
http://jsfiddle.net/u2fk3hx0/3/#&togetherjs=FHtk9HdM5v

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, that is probably coming from the server when you make your request. In this function:

```
function submitUser(className, slo){
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
      cache:false,
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/echo/json/',
      data: {
        json:'{"Course":className,"SLO":slo}'
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#ajax-json').html(data.Course);
        $('#ajax-html').html(data.SLO);
      },
      error:function(error){
        alert('there was an error');  
      },
      dataType: 'json'
    });
  });
}
```

...notice the `data` you're passing is going to contain this literal string value:

```
{"Course":className,"SLO":slo}
```

...which is not what you want. Instead, you want to pass JSON that contains the parameters passed to your function. You haven't posted the implementation of this `/echo/json` server-side code, so it's hard to tell for sure how to fix this, but my best guess is that you want to set your `data` property passed to `$.ajax` like this:

```
$.ajax({
  // ...
  data: {
    json: {
      Course: className,
      SLO: slo
    }
  },
  // ...
});
```

The difference here is you're passing an object that's using the actual parameters, rather than a string that has the *names* of your parameters. jQuery should convert your `data` object to a JSON string for you.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the .ajax is, I copied it from another stack overflow post. I'm not knowledgeable about html or java at all.

Comment: ```var limit = 3;
$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
       this.checked = false;
   }
});


function submitUser(className, slo){
$(function() {
 if (className == "") {
 console.log("Need Class Title");
 }
 if(length !=3) {
 console.log("Need 3 SLOs");
 }

 });
}
  
  ```